# How to allow Guest session to access /home or other directories?

Tags: 12.04, directory, guest-session

I want the Guest session to be able to access /home, maybe as read-only, and other directories as well.

Comment: Please see the answers to these questions: [Allowing guest session to access certain user directories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9990/allowing-guest-session-to-access-certain-user-directories) and [How to access mounted file systems as a guest user?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/186279/how-to-access-mounted-file-systems-as-a-guest-user).

Comment: Thanks! The first question is for old Ubuntu releases. I found the answer in the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case it sounds as if you'd better just create a new user account and use that for your 'guests' instead of the guest session feature. As you can see in [the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-help/shell-guest-session.html), it's not a coincidence that you can't access /home from a guest session.

If you persist, you can change the permissions profile of a guest session by editing the applicable file under `/etc/apparmor.d`. In Ubuntu 13.04 it's `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/lightdm`; the file may have a different name in 12.04.