# Sharing folder with guest

Tags: 13.04, chmod, guest-session

I am trying to allow access to the guest account to a folder at /share

I have chmod 775'd and even 777'd the folder to no avail.

I know the guest account is locked down so it cant access /home, /media, etc, but how do I allow the guest account to access (rwx) one folder.

-- 
Please note to those marking as duplicate - the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9990/allowing-guest-session-to-access-certain-user-directories) does not apply to 13.04.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/9990/allowing-guest-session-to-access-certain-user-directories

Comment: This information is over 3 years old and doesn't apply to 13.04, which is why I asked again.

Comment: 2012 is not 3 years old.. unless I'm missing something. Have you even tried the solution there?

Comment: I too would like to question that this question was marked as a duplicate. The answer to the "How to access mounted..." question involves editing of the AppArmor profile, while this particular question has a very specific answer that does not require such editing. IMNSHO, users should not be encouraged to edit package files when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you create the folder `/var/guest-data` for the purpose, and chmod it `0777`. That particular folder is prepared in the guest session feature for sharing files with other users.

The folder is mentioned in the tutorial [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession), where you also can find other guest session related tips and tricks.